# batch find using initializeUnorderedBulkOp() mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm particularly new in NodeJS and MongoDB. I have a situation where I need to get results using multiple queries. I don't want to run each query and then next. Instead, I want to collect(?) the queries in Bulk and then execute them all at once. I am trying with the following code.

```
let bulk = Requests.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
let allTerms = await getAllTerms(market).catch(e => console.error("Error: ", e.message))
allTerms.forEach(term => {
    console.log(term); // Getting printed fine
    bulk.find({ 'term': term['name'], 'currency': market, 'status': 'Live' });
});
console.log("Now bulking"); // this one too, and sequentially
bulk.execute().then((result) => console.log(result)).catch((e) => "Error Occured!"); // But this one is throwing error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Invalid Operation, no operations specified
console.log(":Operations:"); // Above errors being logged before this statement.
```

Is that because Bulk only supports writes? If so, which would be the best alternative for read only executions?

P.S. My mongoose is using `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`

Comment: I'm not sure but should you not be using `var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));` ?  http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html#promisification-on-steroids

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying, Not sure if that's gonna be helpful in Bulk().